# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: XXX-XX-00001IVFUhAAP

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm troubleshooting the following error in an Apex method:

Error "Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0o04000000Pt4hAAC; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: XXX-XX-00001IVFUhAAP: []

I can locate the record with the above id no problem, but what does **XX-XX-00001IVFUhAAP** refer to?

UPDATE

So, after checking with a colleague, he said that 00001IVFUhAAP is the last part of the Account object Id in this specific sandbox.  Maybe this helps someone down the road.

Comment: There's always an unhelpful person that downvotes.

Comment: not sure why the `00001IVFUhAAP` would be an Account Id. Is this the raw error message or is there some apex that is obscuring part of the ID before you see it?

Comment: @cropredy in the sandbox in question, the account object SFID is 0010400001IVFUhAAP.  The SF error message contains the last part of the ID.

Comment: I've never seen this - it is as if either SFDC or some wrapper to your error handling is masking part of the ID in the error message